# link_to_add_association adding two partials instead of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

When I click on "Add User", two rows are added instead of one.
[See it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeIpp.png)

new.html.slim :

```
= page_header

= simple_form_for @instance, url: admin_instance_users_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  table.table.table-hover
    thead
    tr
      th = t('common.name')
      th = t('common.email')
      th = t('common.role')
      th
        div.pull-right
          = link_to_add_association t('.individual.add_user'), f, :invitations,
                  find_selector: 'tbody', insert_using: 'append'
      tbody
        = f.simple_fields_for :invitations, @instance.invitations.select(&:new_record?) do |invitation_form|
          = render 'invitation_fields', f: invitation_form

  = f.button :submit
```

_invitation_fields.html.slim (partial/column being added):

```
= content_tag_for(:tr, f.object, class: 'nested-fields') do
  td = f.input :name, label: false, input_html: { class: 'invitation_name' }
  td = f.input :email, required: true, label: false, input_html: { class: 'invitation_email' }
  td = f.input :role,
               as: :select,
               collection: Instance::UserInvitation.roles.keys,
               label: false,
               label_method: lambda { |role_key| t("instance.users.role.#{role_key}") },
               include_blank: false,
               input_html: { class: 'invitation_role' }
  td = link_to_remove_association  t('.remove'), f
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: First of all, I can't find `insert_using` option for `link_to_add_association` helper. Looks like cocoon gem doesn't provide it. So I would read the docs carefully: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#link_to_add_association

Comment: Then try to handle the before-insert callback like specified here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#canceling-a-callback if the callback is evaluated once then you have some mess up in your layout. Try to place `link_to_add_association` helper under `f.simple_fields_for :invitations...` for example.

Comment: Can you post the related controller code in the question?

Comment: @Pavan Its just a `new` action without nothing in it.

Comment: This sounds like the cocoon javascript is attached multiple times. In most cases this is either a turbolinks error, if you do not include the cocoon.js in the correct place, or you include the cocoon.js multiple times so it attaches multiple times to the link.

Comment: @nathanvda Another part of the project which has almost identical code does not have this issue. Turbolink does not appear to be used.

Comment: "Almost identical" would be the crux then :P Please show us how cocoon.js is included? do you have any other javascript triggering the buttons? Also the `insert_using` seems to suggest you are not using plain/normal cocoon. I found an extension https://github.com/Coursemology/coursemology2/blob/master/app/helpers/application_cocoon_helper.rb but not sure if it has more side-effects? (the extension is pretty straightforward, so I still guess it is a js issue).

Comment: For reference an old issue which seems closely related https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/409

Comment: @nathanvda that happens to be the project I'm working on! This is the [branch](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/tree/invite_user_to_instance) where I'm adding the form. [This](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/blob/invite_user_to_instance/app/assets/javascripts/application.js) is where cocoon is required.

Comment: I do not see any cocoon code yet?

Comment: I just pushed the code. Heres the [Instance](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/blob/invite_user_to_instance/app/models/instance.rb) model that has_many [Instance::UserInvitations](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/blob/invite_user_to_instance/app/models/instance/user_invitation.rb), [view](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/tree/invite_user_to_instance/app/views/instance/user_invitations), [controller](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/blob/invite_user_to_instance/app/controllers/instance/user_invitations_controller.rb) @nathanvda

Comment: Heres a similar [view](https://github.com/dexterleng/coursemology2/blob/invite_user_to_instance/app/views/course/user_invitations/new.html.slim) (line 35) for Course::UserInvitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to an indentation error with tables in HTML.